# Establish a least-cost path between a point and a line (coastline)

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, cost-path

I have a basic level of knowledge of ArcGis Pro. I need to establish a "least cost path" between a point and a line, which, in this case, is the coastline. What is the procedure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.